# How to remove duplicate words removing duplicates not case sensetive

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string

```
str1='This Python is good Good python'
```

I want the output removing duplicates keeping in the first word irrespective of case, for eg. good and Good are considered same as Python python. The output should be

```
output='This Python is good'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

Following a rather traditional approach:

```py
str1 = 'This Python is good Good python'

words_seen = set()
output = []
for word in str1.split():
    if word.lower() not in words_seen:
        words_seen.add(word.lower())
        output.append(word)
output = ' '.join(output)

print(output) # This Python is good
```

A caveat: it would not preserve word boundaries consisting of multiple spaces: `'python   puppy'` would become `'python puppy'`.

A very ugly short version:

```py
words_seen = set()
output = ' '.join(word for word in str1.split() if not (word.lower() in words_seen or words_seen.add(word.lower())))
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to use regular expressions to remove any word for which we can find a duplicate.  The catch is that regex engines move from start to end of a string.  Since you want to retain the first occurrence, we can reverse the string, and then do the cleanup.

```py
str1 = 'This Python is good Good python'
str1_reverse = ' '.join(reversed(str1.split(' ' )))
str1_reverse = re.sub(r'\s*(\w+)\s*(?=.*\b\1\b)', ' ', str1_reverse, flags=re.I)
str1 = ' '.join(reversed(str1_reverse.strip().split(' ' )))
print(str1)  # This Python is good
```